# Comparing the performance of Rust and C, is this a problem with the compilation process?

Tags: c, rust

While looking for data comparing Rust and C, I went to the benchmarkgame site and tried it myself, and it turned out different from the specified results.(rust vs c clang)

https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/rust-clang.html

Each source code is as follows, and it was executed through the compile command shown at the bottom of the source code.

[image: The stated result table of "rust vs clang"]

However, Rust ran the cargo in the nightly version.

- [Rust](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/binarytrees-rust-5.html)
- [C clang](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/program/binarytrees-clang-5.html)

Below is the result of the compiled result measured by time on my pc.

[image: rust vs c clang time checking]

The reason for this result is that I compile incorrectly? Or is it normal for these results to come out in the first place?

I am using intel i7 10700k, 16gb ram.

Comment: Please post text as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: It's quite hard to follow everything in this question and guess the missing parts. Did you try the rust version with `cargo run` as seems to appear in the screenshot ? If so that's the problem: it's a non optimized build.

Comment: Please **search before asking**. The same question is asked again and again and most often the answer is just "compile in release mode".

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow, so the answer is late. Yes. Thanks to the answer below and your answer, I got the answer. thank you. @DenysSéguret

Comment: With command `time cargo run`, you measure compilation time + execution time of debug build. You should run `cargo build --release` then `time ./target/release/binary_name`.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros Or just `cargo run --release`

Comment: @user4815162342 No, this would measure time of *compiling* code while we want to measure time to execute compiled code.

Comment: @AngelicosPhosphoros You're right, I missed that `time` was used to measure the run time. The same remark applies to the accepted answer btw.

Comment: I know! It wasn't a big deal and after the first compilation it seemed that only the runtime time was checked. @AngelicosPhosphoros
If there is a problem in the future, I will try again as you told me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot shows that Rust is being compiled in debug mode, which will make for a poor benchmark. Use `--release` to build it with full optimizations.

```sh
time cargo run --release 21
```

Better yet, use the same build command they did in case the other options are important:

```sh
/opt/src/rust-1.55.0/bin/rustc -C opt-level=3 -C target-cpu=ivybridge --C codegen-units=1 -L /opt/src/rust-libs binarytrees.rs -o binarytrees.rust-5.rust_run
```

Comment: You should edit your answer to avoid measuring time of *compilation*. I suggest to run 2 commands: 1 compile and 2 `time binary-name`.